# Is it possible to host multiple aler9/rtsp-simple-server on the same machine

Tags: docker, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am using this command to start a server on my linux machine:

> docker run -d --rm -it --network=host aler9/rtsp-simple-server

And this command to connect an rtsp stream

> docker run -v $(pwd):$(pwd) --network=host
> linuxserver/ffmpeg:arm64v8-latest -re -stream_loop -1 -i
> $(pwd)/sample.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream

Is it possible to start a second rtsp server and connect rtsp streams to this second server.

What I am trying to do is to simulate multiple cameras with one sub stream for each camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running multiple rtsp servers like so:

```
docker run --rm -it -e RTSP_PROTOCOLS=tcp -p 8554:8554 -p 1935:1935 aler9/rtsp-simple-server
docker run --rm -it -e RTSP_PROTOCOLS=tcp -p 8555:8554 -p 1936:1935 aler9/rtsp-simple-server
docker run --rm -it -e RTSP_PROTOCOLS=tcp -p 8556:8554 -p 1937:1935 aler9/rtsp-simple-server
```

and connect like so:

```
# Connecting to first server
docker run -v $(pwd):$(pwd) --network=host linuxserver/ffmpeg:arm64v8-latest -re -stream_loop -1 -i 
$(pwd)/sample.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream
# Connecting to second server
docker run -v $(pwd):$(pwd) --network=host linuxserver/ffmpeg:arm64v8-latest -re -stream_loop -1 -i $(pwd)/sample.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8555/mystream
# Connecting to third server
docker run -v $(pwd):$(pwd) --network=host linuxserver/ffmpeg:arm64v8-latest -re -stream_loop -1 -i $(pwd)/sample.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8556/mystream
```

This solution  basically uses docker port mapping and map each server to diffrent ports so they won't colide. According to `aler9/rtsp-simple-server` port mapping is working for tcp and might not work for udp.

Solution for udp will require more investigation.